# Interpolate one range of numbers to another in a tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to transform a set of numbers say {0, 4, 6} to a consecutive one {0, 1, 2}.
Currently I am using `Scipy`'s `interp1d` function. My problem is that I want to change each element of a tensor. Is there a better way than broadcasting the `interp1d` function to each element in a tensor? If not how can I achieve this broadcasting of a custom function

Currently I am doing the following:

```py
>>> a = torch.tensor([[0, 6, 4],
                      [4, 0, 4]])
>>> unique_values = np.unique(a)
>>> interpolator = interp1d(unique_values, range(len(unique_values)))
>>> interpolator(a[0, 1])
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace, why do you want to interpolate?

```
a[a==6]=2
a[a==4]=1
```

Should work. If you don't want to hardcode, you can find unique values like you did, sort them and then replace them in a loop.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this :D Thanks